# CSS Blur Filter Performance

Tags: performance, css

I'm creating a website that has an ::after element with a backgound and a CSS3 blur applied. I've noticed that applying the CSS3 blur has a huge detrimental effect on performance.

With CSS3 blur applied, there is about a 10 - 20 frames/second drop (from 60fps).

The reason I used CSS3 filters to apply a blur was because this is generic code applied to images that I want blurred, ie, I don't want to use an image editor to blur the images manually.

```
.blur::after {
    background-image:url(dog.png);
    filter:blur(3px);
}
```

So, my question is, are there alternatives to using filter: to blur an element and its background that have better performance without using an image editor?

ps,
I don't mind using javascript, jquery, css, or html elements.

Comment: You could do a blur through canvas, and that wouldn't have the long term fps issues. Check out : http://creativejs.com/2011/12/day-5-blur-that-canvas/

Comment: Note: @ericjbasti's linked website refers to four articles which are no longer available.

Answer (score 25):

I was having the same problem. I decided to try adding a CSS snippet used for improving performance of 3d CSS translation. It worked! Not sure why - I'd love if someone could enlighten me. (It might just be that the snippet induces GPU rasterization?)

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
backface-visibility: hidden;
perspective: 1000;
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
transform: translateZ(0);
```

Note that I applied these styles to the element overlaying the blurred element.

I only did a very limited amount of testing; if anyone wants to do some rigorous benchmarking or provide some insight into this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am currently also wanting to blur the background on nav/menu dropdown. On mobile devices you can forget about blur, unless you do it like you did, what [is explained in this post on SmashingMagazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/gpu-animation-doing-it-right/). Still going over the post but I think you got it right, not 100% sure, check the article, worth your time for sure if you want to know more how and why this works.

Comment: It is also worth noting that these values should **come first**. After that use your animation values in the selector. Tried it the other way round with opacity and did not work on an old S4, however with HA turned on super smooth just like on a brand new device.

Comment: Looks like it's only the backface-visibility that matters. Just tested.

Comment: I'm not having success with this :/ Firefox is very slow.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem for me!

Comment: rules such as `transform: translateZ(0);` inform the browser to transfer work to the GPU if possible, which takes a load off the CPU

Answer (score 17):

@ericjbasti's comment was useful:

I added

```
<canvas id="myFogCanvas"></canvas>
```

then in scss,

```
.canvaswrapper{position: relative;}

#myFogCanvas{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

then in js

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myFogCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//all the drawing stuff for canvas ... moveTo, lineTo, etc.
ctx.filter = 'blur(15px)';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)';
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.stroke();
```

then I was able to animate the .canvaswrapper div in css with animation @keyframes. You might use var image = new Image(); on canvas and then blur it.

The performance was WAAAYYYY better than using blur in CSS, especially with animations.

Comment: Sadly as of August 2022, [CanvasRenderingContext2D.filter](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_canvasrenderingcontext2d_filter) is still not available in Safari.

Answer (score 2):

The filter: blur() property in css may come in handy in some situations, but you should know of a side effect it has in Safari (tested on version 15.1 as of this writing).

The issue is a nasty performance drop around the element on which the filter is used, making every other interaction extremely slow. And it happens in Safari only. In other browsers everything works well.

One solution I've found so far is to use transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) along with filter on the same element, to force the browser use GPU acceleration for that particular element instead of the CPU.

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

[Got it from this source (click me)](https://graffino.com/til/CjT2jrcLHP-how-to-fix-filter-blur-performance-issue-in-safari)

Comment: This solution is mentioned in the first answer to this question.

Comment: This code made my chrome slower!

Comment: @Kranchi Thanks for your feedback regarding the performance issue in Chrome. It's important to note that while the transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) trick is effective in improving performance in Safari, especially with the filter: blur() property, it might have different effects in other browsers.

I've tested this code on Brave, which is based on the same engine as Chrome (Chromium), and didn't notice significant performance issues. However, it's possible that different versions or settings in Chrome might react differently.

Comment: Here are a few things to consider:

Browser Version: Ensure that you're testing on the latest version of Chrome, as performance characteristics can change with updates.

Testing Environment: Other factors in your testing environment, such as running extensions or particular hardware configurations, might also impact performance.

Alternative Approaches: I'll look into alternative methods that can optimize performance across multiple browsers, including Chrome. If you have any suggestions or insights, they would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In the meantime, if the performance hit in Chrome is a significant concern, you might consider using conditional CSS or JavaScript to apply this fix only in Safari. I understand that this approach has its drawbacks, like increased code complexity, but it could be a temporary workaround until a more universal solution is found.

I'm committed to finding a solution that works well across all major browsers. Your input is invaluable in this process, so thank you for bringing this to my attention!

Comment: @KevinO. I think you are right but at current time, I switched to the JS solution. In fact I made a SVG object based on the image and added blur filter on it. By this solution I didn't sense any delay.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
will-change: contents;
```

Or:

```
will-change: transform;
```

Comment: This didn't make a difference.