# Alternative to blur CSS with better performance

Tags: css

I'm displaying a list of items, and each item has a background image that depends on an item property (an external image URL). The background image must be blurred and with transparency to keep the item text readability (over the background).

This works well in a desktop, but with mobiles, it's consuming too much CPU due to the blurring and the UX decreases considerably.

I wonder if there could be a way to achieve similar behaviour with a better performance. The used blurring value is 100px, so I don't need a "perfect" blurring, just a shadow with a determined colour (depending on the external image URL).

I could use canvas, but if I'm right, it would consume the same CPU (or similar) when blurring.

This is a simplified example of an item:

```css
.item-background-image {
  -webkit-filter: blur(100px);
  -moz-filter: blur(100px);
  -o-filter: blur(100px);
  -ms-filter: blur(100px);
  filter: blur(100px);
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-background-image" style="background: url('http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/180000/velka/splash-in-dark-blue.jpg') no-repeat center"></div>
```

Comment: CSS can't detect image color so your basic request is impossible as it stands. Also you can't blur a **background-image** with CSS, only actual images in the HTML...is that what you are doing?

Comment: @Paulie_D I use an inline CSS rule with the image URL (`background: url("the URL")`) and the filter `blur` for those elements.

Comment: Then you aren't blurring the *background* you're blurring the whole element, that's not the same. Some code in a demo here would be useful.

Comment: @Paulie_D You're right, it's bad expressed. Added an example.

Comment: Regardless, as I said, CSS can't detect color so this isn't possible.

Comment: It might be better to give the div **content** a background of its own. Perhaps a highly transparent white color?

Comment: There might be some improvement to be had if you can force hardware accelerated rendering. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713468/css-blur-filter-performance

Answer (score 3):

> so I don't need a "perfect" blurring, just a shadow with a determined colour

Would an `inset` `box-shadow` suffice?

```css
body {
  background: #212121;
}

div {
  background: tomato;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px 15px #212121;
  height: 192px;
  width: 192px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Yes, but the color must depend on the external image url.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Color Thief to determine the main color of the image and then apply it to a box-shadow or something similar.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Thanks!